# Given $p$ prime and $k$ a non-prime positive integer $k<p$, is there at least 1 prime of the form $6(pn+k)+5$ with $n\in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

Given $p$ prime and $k$ a non-prime positive integer with $k<p$, is there at least 1 prime of the form $6(pn+k)+5$ with $n\in \mathbb{N}$?

I don't if this statement is true, i think it is because there are infinite primes of the form $6q+5$ where $q\in\mathbb{Z}$, but i don't know how to use this fact (and the other results of congruence and divisibility) to prove if it's true or not.

I can only use Congruence and Divisibility results of elementary number theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems false, choose $p=7$, $k=5$, then $6(pn+k)+5$$=42n+35=7(6n+5)$ is a composite number for $n \geq 1$.

More generally, $6(pn+k)+5=(6p)\cdot n+(6k+5)$, so you find counterexamples by finding $p,k$ with $p \mid 6k+5$. If $p \nmid 6k+5$ for all $k<p$, then $(6p,6k+5)=1$ and [Dirichlet theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) ensures the sequence will contain a prime (infinitely many actually).

To address the updated question with $k$ non-prime, the above still applies and we can choose $p=13$, $k=10$.

Comment: i forgot to say that k cannot be prime, sorry.

Comment: @user8785084 Okay, I've updated the answer to give such example as well.